# Retrieve preferences from intelliJ platform IDE

Tags: java, android, intellij-plugin

I am writing plugin for Android Studio in Java and currently need to determine user's android SDK location. As far as I know, the location of SDK can be set by user in: 
*Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance and Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Location field*

Is it possible to retrieve the value of this field programatically for further use in my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using `IdeSdks.getInstance().getAndroidSdkPath()`

Comment: Definitely what I needed!